# How to create SoundCloud api object?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, soundcloud

In my iPhone app, I'm trying to allow users to post an audio track to Facebook via Soundcloud. I've been going through [this tutorial](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Sharing.md) and have reached this line of code:

```
 [api performMethod:@"GET" onResource:@"me/connections.json"
     withParameters:nil context:nil userInfo:nil];
```

My question is going to show how much of a novice I am in this, but: How do I instantiate the `api` object? Is it a part of a library? What class is it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the test projects it shows you in the app delegate how to create the API object.

Comment: It took a bit of clicking around, but I believe you mean this page: https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md